# Putting a background div for a calculator

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a black background behind jus the elements of my calculator. I have tried multiple positions, margins, heights, widths...etc to no avail. The closest I can get creates an extended page, but I would like the body to have its own background and the calculator to have a different one—without moving elements.

Any help is appreciated.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-style: sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #00AAFF, #00FF6C);
}

.background {
    background-color: black;
    z-index:-1;
    position:relative;
}

.calculator {
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
    grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto) repeat(5, 100px);
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="background">
        <div class="calculator">
            <div class="output">
                <div data-previous-operand class="previous-operand"></div>
                <div data-current-operand class="current-operand"></div>
            </div>
            <button data-allClear>AC</button>
            <button data-switch-signs>+/-</button>
            <button data-percentage>%</button>
            <button data-operation>÷</button>
            <button data-number>7</button>
            <button data-number>8</button>
            <button data-number>9</button>
            <button data-operation>x</button>
            <button data-number>4</button>
            <button data-number>5</button>
            <button data-number>6</button>
            <button data-operation>-</button>
            <button data-number>1</button>
            <button data-number>2</button>
            <button data-number>3</button>
            <button data-operation>+</button>
            <button data-number class="span-two">0</button>
            <button data-number>.</button>
            <button data-equals>=</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, haven't you tried to center the calculator div inside its background parent (using flexbox for instance), add some padding to the calculator box and set a different background color?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking for a black background on the calculator buttons, here is the code

```css
    *,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-style: sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #00AAFF, #00FF6C);
}

.background {
    z-index:-1;
    position:relative;
}

.calculator {
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
    grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto) repeat(5, 100px);
    position: relative;
}

button { /* This is the important part */
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="background">
        <div class="calculator">
            <div class="output">
                <div data-previous-operand class="previous-operand"></div>
                <div data-current-operand class="current-operand"></div>
            </div>
            <button data-allClear>AC</button>
            <button data-switch-signs>+/-</button>
            <button data-percentage>%</button>
            <button data-operation>÷</button>
            <button data-number>7</button>
            <button data-number>8</button>
            <button data-number>9</button>
            <button data-operation>x</button>
            <button data-number>4</button>
            <button data-number>5</button>
            <button data-number>6</button>
            <button data-operation>-</button>
            <button data-number>1</button>
            <button data-number>2</button>
            <button data-number>3</button>
            <button data-operation>+</button>
            <button data-number class="span-two">0</button>
            <button data-number>.</button>
            <button data-equals>=</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean. if you want a background color for your calculator container that holds buttons you should give it width and height also to your body too. then put your calculator in center of your body.

apply this style to your code:

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-style: sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00aaff, #00ff6c);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.background {
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}

.calculator {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto) repeat(5, 100px);
  position: relative;
}
```